# TYPO3 How i get {data.header} when Content Element is parsed

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Problem: I have a page with backend layout and a column has a plugin and a content element "header". Content is then parsed like this `<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{content}</f:format.html>`

How can I get the fields from the elements. Like header, subheader (data.header) from the content element "header"?

With `<f:debug>` the fields don't appear because they are parsed direct.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the page layout, you can't access the content elements.
You need to look for the templates of the content element.
If you use Fluid Styled Content, there is a Fluid template in the extension where you can access the field `header`.

Comment: in the Template i get something like this :
contentTest => ' <a id=""></a> <div class="container">
       <h2 class=""> HeaderTest </h2>
       </div> ' (182 chars) 
and not {data.header}...thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

The fluid variable `content` in your page fluid template contains a string of HTML.

The rendering from the tt_content records already is done. probably in the typoscript declaration of that variable.

There are two possible ways:

1. Basic: declaration as variable in the declaration of the page template

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = ...
    variables {
        content < styles.content.get
        :
    }
}
```

2. or you define that fluid variable inside of your fluid template:

```xml
<f:variable name="content"><f:cObject typoscriptOjectPath="lib.content" /></f:variable>
```

and then in typoscript you have:

```
lib.content < styles.content.get
```

---

remember: `styles.content.get` is a predeclaration of a `CONTENT` object which selects all tt_content records of the current page in column 0. There are variants where you can select the column in a parameter.

in modern installations the rendering of tt_content records is done with FSC (Fluid Styled Content), which means: there is a set of FLUID templates, partials, layouts which work like any FLUID: you have FLUID variables, which here are based on the fields of the tt_content record and you use viewhelper to render a nice HTML (or any other type of **string**)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its already defined like this:

content < styles.content.get
contentFullwidthAdditional.select.where = colPos = 4

And like u say i become a html string in the Fluid template.
Is there a possibility to take as variable or setting the header from the header content element in the typoscript before is parsed?

Thanks

Comment: you can build a viewhelper which adds the tt_content records in an array variable. But that would be very strange and complicated. as said: tt_content records have their own FLUID templating, where you can access each field in its own variable.

Comment: maybe you should tell why you want to access these fields out of context. I suspect something where the solution is much easier than you might think.